# How to set storage engine in Django with MySQL connector/python as backend

Tags: python, mysql, django

I tried setting

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass', 
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
          'init_command' : 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
        },
    }
}
```

(UPD: updated the above code so ppl won't get confused that I am not using django settings the right way)

in Django settings, but this backend doesn't accept such connection option...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to use MySQL Connector/Python Django backend, you have to set the `ENGINE` setting to `mysql.connector.django`:

```
DATABASE = {
  'default': {
    ..
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    ..
  }
}
```

Indeed, MySQL Connector/Python does not have the `init_command` connection argument. I can see value in adding an option for setting the default storage engine in the [Django OPTIONS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-OPTIONS) though. If you really want it, I would suggest opening a feature request on http://bugs.mysql.com.

Small note that MySQL 5.6 (and if you start out, you should use this version) has storage engine set to InnoDB by default.

Comment: would you please provide a link to documentation where 'Django OPTIONS' is mentioned, I can't find it

Comment: I have linked it in my answer.

Comment: I have my database entry setup like the one in the OP with the exception of the init_command in OPTIONS, and whenever I try to start my server I get:  KeyError: u'AUTOCOMMIT'   Nothing else, just that. I can completely comment out the OPTIONS and I still get that error. Can't tell where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the entire setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': "MyDatabaseName,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': "MyUsername",
        'PASSWORD': "MyPassword",
        'HOST': "MyHostName",
        'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB'},
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, but there is no such option 'init_command' for the above mentioned connector (see the link)
site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 291, in config
    DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION[key]
KeyError: 'init_command'